# javaws application launch issue in windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7-x64, jnlp, java-web-start, ioexception

I am trying to launch a jws application (using jnlp file) on **windows 7 64-bit** and getting following issue.

```
ERROR [L:org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig F: T:'javawsApplicationMain'] Exception >fixing docBase: {0} 
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)  
at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Unknown Source)  
at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(Unknown Source)  
at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(Unknown Source)  
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:841)  
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:1012)  
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:279)
```

The same file works like a charm on **windows XP**.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: *"Any help is appreciated."*  The question here might be "Why the difference?" or "How to get it to work on Win 7?" But since I don't like guessing, you might edit a question into the ..question.  Be sure to validate the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) before proceeding.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson - trying JaNeLA is an excellent suggestion!  I'd encourage you to make it a reply.  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4  While it might sort 80%+ plus of these weird type of errors, the fact that you started that sentence with 'try' underlines why I won't enter it as an answer (at least, not yet).  My principle is that anything that starts with 'try' should be a comment.  OTOH, if you choose to enter that as an answer, I would probably up-vote.  ..Hey, I'm a hypocrite who expects different things of others, to what I myself do.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewT -  
I found my mistake and the _difference_.  
Turns out jnlp resource attribute "arch", takes "x86" and **"amd64" (even for Intel 64bit)** for "os" = "Windows".  
So avoid **"x86_64"** while using os="Windows".  
Thanks for replies. :)

Comment: @AndrewT -  
JaNeLa is supercool sir.  
Great to validate JNLP files through it.

Comment: @AndrewT -  
Actually I tried JaNeLa and got to know more about jnlp files but it didnt helped me in solving the problem.  
I got the problem solved by changing resource attribute **"arch"**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake and the difference.
Jnlp resource attribute *arch*, takes **"x86"** and **"amd64" (even for Intel 64bit)** for *os = Windows*. So avoid **"x86_64"** while using *os= Windows*.
Also validate your *JNLP* with *JaNeLa* , you may fall into some other errors in which case its an excellent tool to help you out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to validate the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) before proceeding.  Many launch files are invalid and how a JWS client interprets an invalid launch file is indeterminate - it can lead to all sorts of strange errors.